# "Too many open files" and request buffering

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-5

We have an ASP.NET Core 5 app running in a Docker container in AWS.

When it receives a burst of HTTP POST requests, I get this error in the logs:

```
System.IO.IOException: Too many open files
    at Interop.ThrowExceptionForIoErrno(ErrorInfo errorInfo, String path, Boolean isDirectory, Func`2 errorRewriter)
    at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.Open(String path, OpenFlags flags, Int32 mode)
    at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options)
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.FileBufferingReadStream.CreateTempFile()
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.FileBufferingReadStream.ReadAsync(Memory`1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadAsync[TValue](Stream utf8Json, Type returnType, JsonSerializerOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonInputFormatter.ReadRequestBodyAsync(InputFormatterContext context, Encoding encoding)
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonInputFormatter.ReadRequestBodyAsync(InputFormatterContext context, Encoding encoding)
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.BodyModelBinder.BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ParameterBinder.BindModelAsync(ActionContext actionContext, IModelBinder modelBinder, IValueProvider valueProvider, ParameterDescriptor parameter, ModelMetadata metadata, Object value, Object container)
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerBinderDelegateProvider.<>c_DisplayClass0_0.<<CreateBinderDelegate>g_Bind|0>d.MoveNext()
```

Going through the exception trace above we can see that:

1. This is happening in the MVC middleware (this is, before it gets to our own Controller code)
2. This is happening when the `FileBufferingReadStream` is trying to create a new file to disk when reading the input stream (see source code [here](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities/FileBufferingReadStream.cs)). This gets called when you [enable buffering](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/re-reading-asp-net-core-request-bodies-with-enablebuffering/) in your solution.

What we have so far is: something is enabling buffering in the solution, which causes us to write to disk every time we get a request with a long body (happens most of the time). However, I have removed all code that calls `EnableBuffering` from my solution. Is there any code in a library/framework that can be enabling buffering from us? Is this controlled by some environmental variable that could be part of the environment this is running in?

Edit:

This is my `Program.cs` class (I have omitted some stuff for privacy):

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var webHost = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
    await webHost.RunAsync();
}

public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
{
    return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
        {
            logging.ClearProviders();
            logging.AddConsole();
            logging.AddDebug();
            logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Information);
        })
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            webBuilder.CaptureStartupErrors(false);
            webBuilder.UseSentry();
        })
        .ConfigureServices(services => { });
}
```

and this is my `Startup.cs` class:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    private IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<Config>(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));

        services.AddApiVersioning(version =>
        {
            version.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);
            version.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
            version.ReportApiVersions = true;
        });

        services.AddLogging();
        
        //... DI config here

        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddHealthChecks();

        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo {Title = "MyApp", Version = "v1"});
        });
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IMainIndexer elastic)
    {
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/healthcheck", new HealthCheckOptions
            {
                Predicate = _ => true,
                ResponseWriter = UIResponseWriter.WriteHealthCheckUIResponse
            });
            endpoints.MapGet("/",
                async context =>
                {
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync(
                        "<html><body>Welcome to MyApp</body></html>");
                });
        });
    }
}
```

We have tried some workarounds, like using a different Docker base image and using Newtonsoft instead of `System.Text` and we still get the same issue. Am I missing something?

Comment: @smoksnes root cause found (see answer). But thanks for your suggestion to post Program and Startup... that forced me to re-read it and made me think about Sentry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the question, the issue is caused by something in the middleware enabling request buffering.

We've found out that this was caused by [Sentry](https://sentry.io).

You can see [here](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-dotnet/blob/main/src/Sentry.AspNetCore/SentryMiddleware.cs) that Sentry calls `EnableBuffering()`.

When we removed this line from `Program.cs`

```
WebBuilder.UseSentry();
```

and ran the same load again, the errors were gone.